# How to append Java object to post request

Tags: http, post, serialization

Can objects be appended to post requests in Java or do they have to be converted to Strings first? I know for sure they can be sent as a String using the NameValuePair class, but is there a way to send a serializable plain old Java object through a post request? How would I do that?

EDIT: I found an example, but the post request isn't going through... this is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/test123/User");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // to be able to write.
        conn.setDoInput(true); // to be able to read.

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(myObj);
        out.close();
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: is there a way to do this without using json objects? As in directly sending a java object? or is json the only/best way

Comment: depends on server you're sending it to

Comment: What if the server is just using a Java servlet?

Comment: good luck! @user3125693